# How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm beginning python and I'm trying to use a two-dimensional list, that I initially fill up with the same variable in every place. I came up with this:

```
def initialize_twodlist(foo):
    twod_list = []
    new = []
    for i in range (0, 10):
        for j in range (0, 10):
            new.append(foo)
        twod_list.append(new)
        new = []
```

It gives the desired result, but feels like a workaround. Is there an easier/shorter/more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Just a small (or significant, depending on who is watching) nitpick :
lists are not arrays. If you want arrays, use numpy.

Comment: [This question is similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662475/python-multi-dimensional-array-initialization-without-a-loop): it discusses the initialization of multidimensional arrays in Python.

Comment: @ArnabDatta How would you initialize a multidimensional array in numpy, then?

Comment: @AndersonGreen http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#arrays-creation

Comment: You can arrange data in an array like structure in default Python but it's not nearly as efficient or useful as a NumPy array. Especially if you want to deal with large data sets. Here's some documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.creation.html

Answer (score 418, accepted):

A pattern that often came up in Python was

```
bar = []
for item in some_iterable:
    bar.append(SOME EXPRESSION)
```

which helped motivate the introduction of list comprehensions, which convert that snippet to

```
bar = [SOME_EXPRESSION for item in some_iterable]
```

which is shorter and sometimes clearer. Usually, you get in the habit of recognizing these and often replacing loops with comprehensions.

Your code follows this pattern twice

```
twod_list = []                                       \                      
for i in range (0, 10):                               \
    new = []                  \ can be replaced        } this too
    for j in range (0, 10):    } with a list          /
        new.append(foo)       / comprehension        /
    twod_list.append(new)                           /
```

Comment: By the way,

    [[foo]*10 for x in xrange(10)]

can be used to get rid of one comprehension. The problem is that multiplication does a shallow copy, so

    new = [foo] * 10
    new = [new] * 10

will get you a list containing the same list ten times.

Comment: Similarly, `[foo] * 10` is a list with the same exact `foo` 10 times, which may or may not be important.

Comment: we can use the simplest thing:
wtod_list = [[0 for x in xrange(10))] for x in xrange(10)]

Comment: bar = [SOME EXPRESSION for item in some_iterable (Selection Condition)]

Comment: @Scott Wolchok and Mike Graham - Very important point to make that the multiply with lists copies references to the same list. How do you instantiate an MxN matrix without append?

Comment: @mdude380 For an MxN array, you'd use numpy http://stackoverflow.com/a/2397147/192839

Comment: For Mike Graham's comment about `[foo] * 10`: This means that this wouldn't work if you're filling an array with random numbers (evaluates `[random.randint(1,2)] * 10` to `[1] * 10` or `[2] * 10` which means that you get an array of all 1s or 2s, instead of a random array.

Comment: Adding to @TzuLi 's comment, list1 =  [ [ 1 ] ]* 10 would store one copy of list i.e [1] in memory and all elements of list1 would refer to the common list. Therefore, if we were to do
list1[0].append(2), all elements of list1 would be [1,2].

Answered in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842423/10831140

Answer (score 593):

To initialize a two-dimensional list in Python, use

```
t = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3)]
```

But don't use `[[v]*n]*n`, it is a trap!

```
>>> a = [[0]*3]*3
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]=1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: yes, I fell into this trap, too. It's because `*` is copying the `address` of the object (list).

Comment: Upvoted, since this got me. To be clearer, `[[0] * col for _ in range(row)]`.

Comment: Why does it work for the first dimension but not the second? `l = [0] * 3` followed by `l[0] = 1` yields `[1, 0, 0]` just fine.

Comment: Found the answer for why the first dimension works but not the second. List multiplication makes a shallow copy. When you assign to an index, it does a proper change, but access does not, so when you do `a[x][y] = 2`, it's accessing, not assigning, for the xth index - only the yth access is actually changed. This page helped me explain with diagrams that are probably better than what I tried explaining in this comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/

Comment: @ShivanshRajolia-HeLleR  *which* future versions?  I just ran into this *garbage/crap* behavior in python3.9 !

Comment: Why does python not have a professional function to initialise an n dimensional list?

Comment: Just use Colab and encounter the exact same issue... wasted my 3 hours to debug...But you are a life saver, thank you, upvoted

Comment: do a benchmark, `[ [0]*col for _ in range(row) ]` more faster than `[[0 for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]`

Comment: Doesn't the first * also copy the address of the list and have the same issue?

Answer (score 273):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [[foo for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
# x is now a 10x10 array of 'foo' (which can depend on i and j if you want)
```

Comment: since the size (10) is same its fine, if not the nested loop have to come first [foo for j in range(range_of_j)] for i in range(range_of_i)]

Comment: This answer works fine but I since we iterate `i` for rows and `j` for columns, I think it should be better to swap `i` and `j` in your syntax for better understanding and change the range to 2 different numbers.

Answer (score 153):

**This way is faster** than the nested list comprehensions

```
[x[:] for x in [[foo] * 10] * 10]    # for immutable foo!
```

Here are some python3 timings, for small and large lists

```
$python3 -m timeit '[x[:] for x in [[1] * 10] * 10]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit '[[1 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.44 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit '[x[:] for x in [[1] * 1000] * 1000]'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 msec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit '[[1 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 27 msec per loop
```

Explanation:

`[[foo]*10]*10` creates a list of the same object repeated 10 times. You can't just use this, because modifying one element will modify that same element in each row!

`x[:]` is equivalent to `list(X)` but is a bit more efficient since it avoids the name lookup. Either way, it creates a shallow copy of each row, so now all the elements are independent.

All the elements are the same `foo` object though, so if **`foo` is mutable**, you can't use this scheme., you'd have to use

```
import copy
[[copy.deepcopy(foo) for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
```

or assuming a class (or function) `Foo` that returns `foo`s

```
[[Foo() for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
```

Comment: This seems to be much less readable than any other solution presented. Also, `copy.deepcopy` is not reliable and not something useful very often.

Comment: @Mike, did you miss the part in bold? if foo is mutable, none of the other answers here work (unless you are not mutating foo at all)

Comment: You cannot correctly copy arbitrary objects using `copy.deepcopy`. You need a plan specific to your data if you have an arbitrary mutable object.

Comment: If you need speed that badly in a loop, it may be time to use Cython, weave, or similar...

Comment: This is also useful in case you want to initialise lists to the same random integer

Comment: @MikeGraham FYI python 2.5 made this more useful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684881/python-implementation-of-shallow-and-deep-copy-constructors -- a custom class for which deepcopy's default behavior is wrong should implement `__ deepcopy __`. That is where "the plan specific to data type" belongs.  gnibbler: Thanks -- The deepcopy solution is perfect for the common mutable case where foo is an empty list!

Comment: How exactly would I use the syntax of the first line? I just get a "NameError: name 'foo' is not defined". Is a `foo = None` before this line the right way to go? (at least it all seems to work as expected then)
**EDIT**: Ahh, I got it. The field gets initialised with the value I assign the variable first. So a `foo = 0` at the beginning would init the 2d-array with zeros... Never mind :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy i think you interchanged `x` and `y`. Shouldn't it be `[[copy.deepcopy(foo) for y in range(10)] for x in range(10)]`

Comment: Could anyone quote the documentation on [[foo]*10]*10? I understand why it does not work, but then why does [foo]*10 create 10 different objects? I thought all objects are pointer types in Python... and where exactly is * documented?

Comment: @Nils `[foo]*10` doesn't create 10 different objects - but it's easy to overlook the difference in the case where foo is immutable, like an `int` or `str`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation! Now where is this documented? Googling for * does not really work for me.

Answer (score 77):

To initialize a two-dimensional array in Python:

```
a = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]
```

Comment: To initialize all values to 0, just use `a = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]`.

Comment: `[[0 for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]` is slow, use `[ [0]*cols for _ in range(rows)]`

Answer (score 39):

```
[[foo for x in xrange(10)] for y in xrange(10)]
```

Comment: xrange() has been removed in python3.5

Comment: why this doesn't work: [0 * col] * row. When I modify some element it replicates at other places. But I don't understand why?

Comment: Because that does exactly the same thing as the code in the question.

Comment: @codemuncher The reason that `[[0] * col] * row` doesn't do what you want is because when you initialize a 2d list that way, Python will not create distinct copies of each row. Instead it will init the outer list with pointers to the same copy of `[0]*col`. Any edit you make to one of the rows will then be reflected in the remaining rows since they are all actually pointing to the same data in memory.

Comment: Just a thought but aren't all these lists no good for appending to?  Ie. if i want an empty 2D list of dimension 3 *6 and want to append to index[0][0], [1][0], [2][0] and so on to fill up all 18 elements, none of these answers will work right?

Answer (score 25):

Usually when you want multidimensional arrays you don't want a list of lists, but rather a numpy array or possibly a dict.

For example, with numpy you would do something like

```
import numpy
a = numpy.empty((10, 10))
a.fill(foo)
```

Comment: Although `numpy` is great, I think it might be a bit of overkill for a beginner.

Comment: numpy provides a multidimensional array type. Building a good multidimensional array out of lists is possible but less useful and harder for a beginner than using numpy. Nested lists are great for some applications, but aren't usually what someone wanting a 2d array would be best off with.

Comment: after a few  years of occasionally doing serious python apps the quirks of standard python arrays seem to warrant just going ahead with `numpy`. +1

Answer (score 24):

**For those who are confused why `[['']*m]*n` is not good to use.**

Python uses a system known as “Call by Object Reference” or “Call by assignment”.([More info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/))

Best way is `[['' for i in range(columns)] for j in range(rows)]`
This will solve all the problems.

For more Clarification 
Example:

```
>>> x = [['']*3]*3
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
>>> x[0][0] = 1
>>> print(x)
[[1, '', ''], [1, '', ''], [1, '', '']]
```

```
>>> y = [['' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
>>> y[0][0]=1
>>> print(y)
[[1, '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I was looking for this.

Comment: Python *never* uses call by reference

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for highlighting this. :)

Answer (score 11):

You can do just this:

```
[[element] * numcols] * numrows
```

For example:

```
>>> [['a'] *3] * 2
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

But this has a undesired side effect:

```
>>> b = [['a']*3]*3
>>> b
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
>>> b[1][1]
'a'
>>> b[1][1] = 'b'
>>> b
[['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'a']]
```

Comment: In my experience, this "undesirable" effect is often a source of some very bad logical errors. In my opinion, this approach should be avoided, instead @Vipul's answer is much better.

Comment: this approach works good , why in comments some people refer it is as bad ?

Comment: Because of the undersired side effect, you cannot really treat it as a matrix. If you dont need to alter the contents then it'll be all right.

Comment: this is bad because you are soft-copying the same row in your matrix and changing one element will change all the rest.

Answer (score 11):

```
twod_list = [[foo for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
```

for n is number of rows, and m is the number of column, and foo is the value.

Answer (score 8):

If it's a sparsely-populated array, you might be better off using a dictionary keyed with a tuple:

```
dict = {}
key = (a,b)
dict[key] = value
...
```

Answer (score 8):

Code:

```
num_rows, num_cols = 4, 2
initial_val = 0
matrix = [[initial_val] * num_cols for _ in range(num_rows)]
print(matrix) 
# [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

`initial_val` must be immutable.

Answer (score 6):

```
t = [ [0]*10 for i in [0]*10]
```

for each element a new `[0]*10` will be created ..

Answer (score 4):

use the simplest think to create this.

```
wtod_list = []
```

and add the size:

```
wtod_list = [[0 for x in xrange(10)] for x in xrange(10)]
```

or if we want to declare the size firstly. we only use:

```
   wtod_list = [[0 for x in xrange(10)] for x in xrange(10)]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Incorrect Approach: [[None*m]*n]

```
>>> m, n = map(int, raw_input().split())
5 5
>>> x[0][0] = 34
>>> x
[[34, None, None, None, None], [34, None, None, None, None], [34, None, None, None, None], [34, None, None, None, None], [34, None, None, None, None]]
>>> id(x[0][0])
140416461589776
>>> id(x[3][0])
140416461589776
```

With this approach, python does not allow creating different  address space for the outer columns and  will lead to various misbehaviour than your expectation.

#### Correct Approach but with exception:

```
y = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
>>> id(y[0][0]) == id(y[1][0])
False
```

It is good approach but there is exception if you set default value to `None`

```
>>> r = [[None for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
>>> r
[[None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None]]
>>> id(r[0][0]) == id(r[2][0])
True
```

So set your default value properly using this approach.

#### Absolute correct:

Follow the mike's reply of [double loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397192/2176812).

Answer (score 4):

To initialize a 2-dimensional array use:
`arr = [[]*m for i in range(n)]`

actually,
`arr = [[]*m]*n` will create a 2D array in which all n arrays will point to same array, so any change in value in any element will be reflected in all n lists

for more further explanation visit : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/

Comment: Objection: whereas arr = `[[0]*3 for i in range(3)]` creates `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`, `arr = [[]*3 for i in range(3)]` creates `[[], [], []]` so you cannot reference arr[2][2], only arr[2], i.e. this is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

Initializing a 2D matrix of size m X n with 0

```
m,n = map(int,input().split())
l = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
print(l)
```

Comment: Can you tell me, when we do [[0]*m]*n it creates similar 2d list but doesn't index like a matrix?

Comment: @Rehan Yes that is absolute garbage behavior by python. I just puzzled over that for tens of minutes

Answer (score 4):

I use it this way to create `MxN` matrix where `m = number(rows)` and `n = number(columns)`.

```
arr = [[None]*(n) for _ in range(m)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Matrix={}
for i in range(0,3):
  for j in range(0,3):
    Matrix[i,j] = raw_input("Enter the matrix:")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

If you use *numpy*, you can easily create 2d arrays:

```
import numpy as np

row = 3
col = 5
num = 10
x = np.full((row, col), num)
```

x

```
array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Comment: Given the just *lousy* behavior of python's `[[0]*M]*N` which creates the "trap" described by @JasonChan - yes let's use `numpy` (which is really the primary reason to use python anyways)

Answer (score 2):

```
row=5
col=5
[[x]*col for x in [b for b in range(row)]]
```

The above will give you a 5x5 2D array

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

It is using nested list comprehension.
Breakdown as below:

```
[[x]*col for x in [b for b in range(row)]]
```

[x]*col --> final expression that is evaluated
for x in --> x will be the value provided by the iterator
[b for b in range(row)]] --> Iterator.

[b for b in range(row)]] this will evaluate to [0,1,2,3,4] since row=5
so now it simplifies to

```
[[x]*col for x in [0,1,2,3,4]]
```

This will evaluate to 
[[0]*5 for x in [0,1,2,3,4]] --> with x=0 1st iteration
[[1]*5 for x in [0,1,2,3,4]] --> with x=1 2nd iteration
[[2]*5 for x in [0,1,2,3,4]] --> with x=2 3rd iteration
[[3]*5 for x in [0,1,2,3,4]] --> with x=3 4th iteration
[[4]*5 for x in [0,1,2,3,4]] --> with x=4 5th iteration

Answer (score 1):

As @Arnab and @Mike pointed out, an array is not a list. Few differences are 1) arrays are fixed size during initialization 2) arrays normally support lesser operations than a list.

Maybe an overkill in most cases, but here is a basic 2d array implementation that leverages hardware array implementation using python ctypes(c libraries)

```
import ctypes
class Array:
    def __init__(self,size,foo): #foo is the initial value
        self._size = size
        ArrayType = ctypes.py_object * size
        self._array = ArrayType()
        for i in range(size):
            self._array[i] = foo
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self._array[index]
    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        self._array[index] = value
    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

class TwoDArray:
    def __init__(self,columns,rows,foo):
        self._2dArray = Array(rows,foo)
        for i in range(rows):
            self._2dArray[i] = Array(columns,foo)

    def numRows(self):
        return len(self._2dArray)
    def numCols(self):
        return len((self._2dArray)[0])
    def __getitem__(self,indexTuple):
        row = indexTuple[0]
        col = indexTuple[1]
        assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
               and col >=0 and col < self.numCols(),\
               "Array script out of range"
        return ((self._2dArray)[row])[col]

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    twodArray = TwoDArray(4,5,5)#sample input
    print(twodArray[2,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

An empty 2D matrix may be initialized in the following manner:

temp=[[],[]]

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've found for teaching new programmers, and without using additional libraries. I'd like something better though.

```
def initialize_twodlist(value):
    list=[]
    for row in range(10):
        list.append([value]*10)
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way :

```
import numpy as np
twoD = np.array([[]*m]*n)
```

For initializing all cells with any 'x' value use :

```
twoD = np.array([[x]*m]*n
```

Answer (score 0):

Often I use this approach for initializing a 2-dimensional array

`n=[[int(x) for x in input().split()] for i in range(int(input())]`

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern to add dimensions could be drawn from this series:

```
x = 0
mat1 = []
for i in range(3):
    mat1.append(x)
    x+=1
print(mat1)


x=0
mat2 = []
for i in range(3):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(4):
        tmp.append(x)
        x+=1
    mat2.append(tmp)

print(mat2)


x=0
mat3 = []
for i in range(3):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(4):
        tmp2 = []
        for k in range(5):
            tmp2.append(x)
            x+=1
        tmp.append(tmp2)
    mat3.append(tmp)

print(mat3)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question already has a massively up-voted accepted answer. At first sight, this post doesn't actually answer the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing I understood is: While initializing an array(in any dimension) We should give a default value to all the positions of array. Then only initialization completes. After that, we can change or receive new values to any position of the array. The below code worked for me perfectly

```
N=7
F=2

#INITIALIZATION of 7 x 2 array with deafult value as 0
ar=[[0]*F for x in range(N)]

#RECEIVING NEW VALUES TO THE INITIALIZED ARRAY
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(F):
        ar[i][j]=int(input())
print(ar)
```

Comment: This is still the trap, as described in the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[[0]*n]*m
np.array(lst)
```

initialize all matrix m=rows and n=columns

Comment: Can you please format code as code? It would be way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a dictionary to hold a two-dimensional array.

```
twoD = {}
twoD[0,0] = 0
print(twoD[0,0]) # ===> prints 0
```

This just can hold any 1D, 2D values and to initialize this to `0` or any other int value, use **collections**.

```
import collections
twoD = collections.defaultdict(int)
print(twoD[0,0]) # ==> prints 0
twoD[1,1] = 1
print(twoD[1,1]) # ==> prints 1
```

Answer (score -5):

```
from random import randint
l = []

for i in range(10):
    k=[]
    for j in range(10):
        a= randint(1,100)
        k.append(a)

    l.append(k)




print(l)
print(max(l[2]))

b = []
for i in range(10):
    a = l[i][5]
    b.append(a)

print(min(b))
```

Comment: Please add some text describing what your code does.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).