# Python multi-dimensional array initialization without a loop

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to initialize a multi-dimensional array / list without using a loop?

Comment: This question is slightly vague: do you want to initialize an empty multidimensional array, or do you want to initialize the multidimensional array to a specific set of values?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure there *is* a way

```
arr = eval(`[[0]*5]*10`)
```

or

```
arr = eval(("[[0]*5]+"*10)[:-1])
```

but it's horrible and wasteful, so everyone uses loops (usually list comprehensions) or numpy

Comment: Marking it as accepted as best reflects the question. numpy is not a part of standard Python installation.

Comment: This has the drawback of creating references to the same objects, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3662548/393885)

Comment: @black_puppydog, no it doesn't. That's why `eval` is used here

Comment: This answer explains how to initialize a multidimensional array using numpy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3662541/975097

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your real needs, the de facto "standard" package [Numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) might provide you with exactly what you need.

You can for instance create a multi-dimensional array with

```
numpy.empty((10, 4, 100))  # 3D array
```

(initialized with *arbitrary values*) or create the same arrays with *zeros* everywhere with

```
numpy.zeros((10, 4, 100))
```

Numpy is very fast, for array operations.

Comment: Hm... would both of these examples create a 10 x 4 x 100 array?

Comment: They most definitely do. You can check this by doing `a = numpy.empty((10, 4, 100)); print a.shape`.

Answer (score 8):

The following does not use any special library, nor eval:

```
arr = [[0]*5 for x in range(6)]
```

and it doesn't create duplicated references:

```
>>> arr[1][1] = 2
>>> arr
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure, you can just do

```
mylist = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]
         ]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I'm not asking how that will look for a matrix 1000 X 1000...

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it's possible.

You can do something like this:

```
>>> a = [[0] * 5] * 5
```

to create a 5x5 matrix, but it is repeated objects (which you don't want). For example:

```
>>> a[1][2] = 1
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

You almost certainly need to use some kind of loop as in:

```
[[0 for y in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: >>> a = [[0] * 5] * 5
It is a bit dangers way.. maybe it is good if you use zero. But if you try to put there your variable. You get list of lists that references to same value. for example when you set a[1][1] = 5 - all list will have item in 1 position as 5!

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is your friend :D

It's a pretty naive implementation but it works!

```
dim = [2, 2, 2]

def get_array(level, dimension):
    if( level != len(dimension) ):
        return [get_array(level+1, dimension) for i in range(dimension[level])]
    else:
        return 0

print get_array(0, dim)
```

Comment: This is just what I was after, thanks! My only caveat is I prefer sending down a shortened dimension array, instead of two parameters, as in: [get_array(dimension[1:]) for j in xrange(dimension[0])]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you what to initialize the array to, but sure. You can use a list comprehension to create a 5×3 array, for instance:

```
>>> [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(5)]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

>>> [[3*y+x for x in range(3)] for y in range(5)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

Yes, I suppose this still has loops—but it's all done in one line, which I presume is the intended meaning of your question?

Comment: That doesn't count as using a loop?

Comment: Docs specify it as a way to initialize multidimensional list. For a one-dimension list the following initialisation is possible `list = [5] * 10`, but can't get it to work with more dimensions. Seems that when you do `list = [[5]*5]*5`, then each sub-dimension will point to the same memory, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[]]
a.append([1,2])
a.append([2,3])
```

Then

```
>>> a
[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing numerical work using Numpy, something like

```
x = numpy.zeros ((m,n))
x = numpy.ones ((m,n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have *arrays*. It has other sequence types ranging from lists to dictionaries without forgetting sets - the right one depends on your specific needs.

Assuming your "array" is actually a list, and "initialize" means allocate a list of lists of *NxM* elements, you can (pseudocode):

- for N times: for M times: add an element
- for N times: add a row of M elements
- write the whole thing out

You say you don't want to loop and that rules out the first two points, but why?
You also say you don't want to write the thing down (in response to JacobM), so how would you exactly do that? I don't know of any other way of getting a data structure without either generating it in smaller pieces (looping) or explicitly writing it down - in any programming language.

Also keep in mind that a initialized but empty list is no better than no list, unless you put data into it. And you don't need to initialize it before putting data...

If this isn't a theoretical exercise, you're probably asking the wrong question. I suggest that you explain what do you need to do with that array.

Comment: You're going to deep into some of the points :)) The point of the question is very simple and it asks what it asks for. I was wondering about different techniques people use for initialization of multidimensional **lists**, and the responses to the question perfectly reflect what I wanted to know. Some people use *de-facto* standard Numpy library. Some people initialize lists using `for` loops obviously. As *JacobM* suggests you can statically initialize the lists, but I point out that it's not applicable for large lists. *gnibbler* suggests very interesting but funky and non-efficient way.

Comment: I was particularly wondering about initialization without `for` loops, as it was already obvious from the docs how you would do that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way:

First without using any loop:

```
[[0] * n] * m
```

Secondly using simple inline list comprehension:

```
[[0 for column in range(n)] for row in range(m)]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use N-dimensional array (ndarray). Here is the link to the documentation. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html