# How to read csv into multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read form an CSV where the first four columns are the indexes for a multi-dimensional array. I get the error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

from:

```
sp = []
csvFile = open("sp.csv", "rb")
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
for row in csvReader:
    print row
    sp[int(row[0])][int(row[1])][int(row[2])][int(row[3])] = float(row[4])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize a dictionary at every dimension eg `sp[int(row[0])]` needs to be assigned to first before you can access it with `[int(row[1])]`

Edit. Depending on your use case, you may get away with

```
sp = {}
sp[(int(row[0]), int(row[1]), ..] = float(row[4])
```

Yet another edit. I was thinking you might use `numpy` and ended up at this question: [Python multi-dimensional array initialization without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662475/python-multi-dimensional-array-initialization-without-a-loop) which actually reflects your problem. It contains a non-`numpy` solution as the accepted answer. You'd need to know the dimensions for this, though.

Comment: sigh, so n^4? thought python was better than that :(

Comment: collections.defaultdict helps but only one level deep

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: Although it would require a lot more memory, you could make the multi-dimensional array a dictionary of dictionaries and thereby avoid having to preallocate every entry in it.

Comment: @martineau my bad was thinking of dictionaries already in my comment. However, even then sp[int(row[0])] default to {} and you need to init it at position[int(row[1])] to a new {} before you can assign to it

Comment: @Nicolas78: It's possible to use `defaultdict` and avoid having to do all that initialization -- it's called [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification). See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array, you could use a dictionary of dictionaries like this to avoid having to preallocate the entire structure beforehand:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

sp = tree()

print 3 in sp[1][2]  # -> False
sp[1][2][3] = 4.1
print 3 in sp[1][2]  # -> True
print sp[1][2][3]  # -> 4.1

sp[9][7][9] = 5.62
sp[4][2][0] = 6.29
```

Comment: This is a thing of beauty.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, can you perhaps please elaborate a bit more? my `sp[1][2][3]` returns `defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10cf05230>, {})`

Comment: That's because you didn't assign a terminal (aka "leaf") value to `sp[1][2][3]` before referencing its contents, so an empty `defaultdict` (aka a "branch" node) got created automatically by default. This is instead of a `KeyError: 3` being raised because the `defaultdict` in `sp[1][2]` -- also automatically created -- doesn't have a value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

How about using **Numpy**? sp.csv might look like this:

```
0,0,0,4.1
1,1,2,5.2
0,1,1,3.2
```

Then, using [Numpy](http://numpy.org/), reading from file become a one-liner:

```
import numpy as np
sp = np.loadtxt('sp.csv', delimiter=',')
```

This yields a 2D record array:

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  4.1],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  2. ,  5.2],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  3.2]])
```

Converting this sparse matrix to a full ndarray works like this, assuming 0-based indexing. I'm not happy with the `idx=` line (there must be a more direct way), but it works:

```
max_indices = sp.max(0)[:-1]
fl = np.zeros(max_indices + 1)
for row in sp:
    idx = tuple(row[:-1].astype(int))
    fl[idx] = row[-1]
```

Resulting in the following ndarray `fl`:

```
array([[[ 4.1,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  3.2,  0. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  5.2]]])
```