# Reading the contents a CSV File into a multi-dimensional Array using Java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I am coding a login screen GUI in Java, which allows users to log into a system. The program refers to a csv file, containing login details, which it gathers the data from.

This is similar to another question I saw, [how to read csv into multidimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23711388/5309838)

But in my case, its in Java, not Python

I'm trying to read data from a csv file, created in Excel into a multi-dimensional array. I understand how to read it into data variable, this is done for every line of the text file. But for the code within the try catch block, which is meant to assign each field of each row, to an element of the usersData[ ][ ] array, just gives me errors.

I've tried all I know to fix it, but without success.

```
public static boolean determineifValid(String userID, String password){
    boolean detailsValid = false;
    // The name of the file 
    String file_Name = "PathologyInterfaceUsers.csv";
    File file = new File(file_Name);
    // The following code block reads the text file in the file_name variable. 
    String usersData[][] = new String[12][3];
    // CSV - comma seperated values 
    String data;
    int firstChar;
    int field_No;
    int i;
    int j;
    i = 0;
    try{            
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            data = inputStream.next();
            // If the data record contains nothing that indicates the end of the file 
            if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                // Nothing happens and nothing needs to be done 
                System.out.println("End of file reached ");
            }else{

            if(i == 0){
            System.out.println("Record No: "+data);
            }else{
                System.out.println(i+"        : "+data);
            }
            field_No = 0;
            firstChar = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < data.length(); j++){
                /* If the current character is a comma separator, then the end of 
                *  the data field has been reached. 
                */
                if((data.charAt(j)) == ','){
                    System.out.println("Field "+(field_No + 1)+" is being copied to"
                            + " the data array");
                    usersData[i][field_No] = data.substring(firstChar, (j-1));

                    System.out.println("The data for field "+(field_No + 1)+"has been "
                            + "assigned to the "+ (field_No + 1) +" column");
                    // The index of the 2nd element of usersData, 'field' is incremented by 1 
                    field_No = field_No + 1;
                    System.out.println("The field_No has been incremented by 1");
                    /* The first character of the next field is the one after the 
                     * comma (value divider)
                    */
                    firstChar = j + 1;
                    System.out.println("Value divider ','");
                }else if(j == data.length()){
                    usersData[i][field_No] = data.substring(firstChar, j);
                }
            }
            i = i + 1;
            }

        }
        inputStream.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("We are so sorry, but an error has occured! ");
    }
```

Comment: What error does it give and what is the stack trace ?

Comment: Without the error we can't help you much, by the way I will try to read every single line and then split it with [the split method of the String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and saving you a lot of time

Comment: Hey guys. Sorry I didn't post the error. But I won't need to anymore because I found a more efficient way of reading a csv. file elsewhere in Stack Overflow. I'll post it for anyone who may need it.

Answer (score -1):

Csv can be way more complicated to process correctly than it looks. Just use a library dedicated for that, such as [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) and save yourself the headache. Here's a simple example:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(file));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).