# How to create and store the following in variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
x = [[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]
```

when I do `print(x)`, I should get the below result:

```
[[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]
```

I am getting an error stating invalid syntax if I try to put it directly

Comment: List elements should be separated by *comma*s (***,***).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about "[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)". This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multi-dimensional array initialization without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662475/python-multi-dimensional-array-initialization-without-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the data by comma.

```
x = [[[0.17966604, 0.3583575, 0.38964075, 0.62007916],[0.30873033, 0.76084626 0.48109448, 0.8554621],[0.25581205, 0.6597363, 0.35912672, 0.70630217]]]
```

Comment: when I do print(x), I should get the below result:

[[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]

Comment: You don't want to access the data of x?

Comment: Then you should initialize the data as string `x = "[[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]"`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[[0.17966604, 0.3583575, 0.38964075, 0.62007916],[0.30873033, 0.76084626, 0.48109448, 0.8554621],[0.25581205, 0.6597363, 0.35912672, 0.70630217]]]
```

Comment: when I do print(x), I should get the below result:

[[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x = [[[0.17966604, 0.3583575, 0.38964075, 0.62007916], [0.30873033, 0.76084626, 0.48109448, 0.8554621], [0.25581205, 0.6597363, 0.35912672, 0.70630217]]]
```

List items must be comma separated,

you can print the individual numbers now using

```
In [2]: for i in x: 
    ...:     for j in i: 
    ...:         for k in j: 
    ...:             print(k) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
0.17966604
0.3583575
0.38964075
0.62007916
0.30873033
0.76084626
0.48109448
0.8554621
0.25581205
0.6597363
0.35912672
0.70630217
```

Comment: Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Edited, try that now, the lists are also comma separated as they are now list items

Answer (score 1):

You need to seperate the list items with a ','

```
x = [[[0.17966604, 0.3583575, 0.38964075, 0.62007916][0.30873033, 0.76084626, 0.48109448, 0.8554621][0.25581205, 0.6597363, 0.35912672, 0.70630217]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to store it as a list, store it as a string. E.g:

```
x = '[[[0.17966604 0.3583575 0.38964075 0.62007916][0.30873033 0.76084626 0.48109448 0.8554621][0.25581205 0.6597363 0.35912672 0.70630217]]]'
```

Comment: I should be able to access      :                                                                                        
   for element in x:                                                                                                                         which will give me the individual [  ]  containing 4 elements each

Comment: @ShubhamPatil i did not get your comment exactly.

Comment: Do you want to store the variable as a string or array?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like this by subclassing `list`:

```py
class ShubhamList(list):
    def __init__(self, _list):
        super().__init__(_list)

    def __str__(self):
        display = str(self.__repr__()).replace(',', ' ').replace(']',']\n')
        return display
```

```py
>>>> import numpy as np

>>>> shubhamlist = ShubhamList(np.random.randn(9).reshape(3,3).tolist())

>>>> print(shubhamlist)

>>>> [[0.24597020426131389  0.6222644287583338  0.08297249039142351]
>>>>   [0.03315975540270755  0.9122494505528221  0.07252409817609973]
>>>>   [0.21316003202865208  0.30553204960841296  0.7116205328650757]
>>>> ]
```