# More elegant way to create a 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, loops, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

I have always written this part of code in this way: every time I need it, I use this python code:

```
for x in range(8):
        a.append([])
        for y in range(8):
            a[x].append(0)
```

However, I'd like to know if there's a way to beautify this piece of code.
I mean, how do you create a bidimensional matrix in python, and fill it with 0?

Comment: this problem is of declaring and initializing two dimensional array is explained nicely [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [nested list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
a = [[0 for y in range(8)] for x in range(8)]
```

which is eqivalent to

```
a = []
for x in range(8):
    row = []
    for y in range(8):
        row.append(0)
    a.append(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is more concise.

```
a = [[0 for i in xrange(8)] for i in xrange(8)]
print a
```

Or you can use [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) if you will do numerical calculations with the array. *Numpy.zeros* function creates a multi dimensional array of zeros.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((8,8))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a = [[0]*8 for _ in xrange(8)]
```

It uses list comprehensions and the fact that the `*` operator can be applied to lists for filling them with `n` copies of a given element.

Or even better, write a generic function for returning matrices of a given size:

```
# m: number of rows, n: number of columns
def create_matrix(m, n):
    return [[0]*n for _ in xrange(m)]

a = create_matrix(8, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Since you don't really care about the values provided by `range`, you can use `_`, which is conventionally stands for a value, which one isn't interested in.

```
>>> z = [[0 for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(z)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists without resorting to use of map(), filter() and/or lambda. The resulting list definition tends often to be clearer than lists built using those constructs.