# 2d list or array: How do I modify one value - ie a unique pointer per cell?

Tags: python

How do I make a list with only one pointer per cell? (I think that is the problem)

Thanks
ps if you are feeling nice, how do I take the spaces out of the print function?

```
class Board(object):
    """board of pieces"""
    def __init__(self):

        self.board = [['0']*7]*6 #6x7 grid
        self.board[3][6] = 8

    def printBoard(self):
        """Display the board array"""
        print self.board
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                print self.board[i][j],
            print "\n",

0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 8
```

Comment: What do you mean with "pointer"? Are you talking of "C" pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite `self.board` as follows

```
self.board = [['0']*7 for i in range(6)]
```

Read about [creating multidimentional](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) lists in Python FAQ.

Here is an excerpt from the answer in the FAQ.

> The reason is that replicating a list with * doesn’t create copies, it
>   only creates references to the existing objects. The *3 creates a list
>   containing 3 references to the same list of length two. Changes to one
>   row will show in all rows, which is almost certainly not what you
>   want.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Board(object):
    """board of pieces"""
    def __init__(self):

        self.board = [['0']*7 for i in range(6)] #6x7 grid
        self.board[3][6] = '8'

    def printBoard(self):
        """Display the board array"""
        print self.board
        for i in range(6):
            print ''.join(self.board[i])
```

Comment: This leaves off the trailing 8 on each line; not sure if that's an issue or not

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398187/981427) and this is the best answer i found there: (I adapted the example)

> You can use list comprehensions
>
> ```
> [x[:] for x in [['0']*7]*6]
> ```
>
> [['0']*7]*6 creates a list of the same object repeated 6 times. You
>   can't just use this, because modifying one element will modify that
>   same element in each row!
>
> x[:] is equivalent to list(X) but is a bit more efficient since it
>   avoids the name lookup. Either way, it creates a shallow copy of each
>   row, so now all the elements are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a dictionary indexed by tuples for multidimensional arrays:

```
class Board(object):
    """board of pieces"""
    WIDTH = 7
    HEIGHT = 6
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = {}
        for i in range(self.HEIGHT):
            for j in range(self.WIDTH):
                self.board[i,j] = 0

        self.board[3,6] = 8

    def printBoard(self):
        """Display the board array"""
        print self.board
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                print self.board[i,j],
            print "\n",
```