# appending nested list - is it supposed to work this way?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected feature in a Python list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists)
>   [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

I wanted to create a nested list of nsize and then append items into it one by one according to a criterion.

For this I wrote it like following ( nsize = 4 )

```
a = [[]] * 4  # which creates on display a = [ [] , [] , [] , [] ]
```

Now I do something like this `a[1].append(3)` which gives me the output `[[3], [3], [3], [3]]`

What am I doing wrong here ? Should'nt only the 2nd list ( a[1] ) be updated with the value 3 ?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing creates a list with 4 references to the same sub-list.

You need to do something like `a = [[] for _ in xrange(4)]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supposed to work that way, even though it is often surprising.  It is equivalent to this

```
b=[]
a=[b]*4
```

Then when you say `a[1].append(3)`, that's just like saying `b.append(3)`.  And since `a` contains four references to that same list, you see it appear four times when you print `a`.