# Python multiple dimension arrays

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

In solving a simple problem regarding a two dimensional array I came across a solution on this site that explained how to declare one in Python using the overload operator.

Example:

```
Myarray = [[0]*3]*3
```

this would produce the following array (list)

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

This seems fine until you use it:

if you assign an element for example:

```
Myarray [0][0] = 1
```

you get the unexpected output:

```
[[1,0, 0],[1,0,0] , [1,0,0]]
```

In effect assigning Myarray [1][0] and Myarray[2][0] at the same time

My solution:

```
Myarray = [[][][]]
for i in range(0,3):
  for j in range (0,3):
     Myarray[i].append(0)
```

This solution works as intended:

```
Marray[0][1] = 1
```

gives you

```
[[1,0, 0],[0,0,0] , [0,0,0]]
```

Is there ***a simpler way*** to do this? This was a solution to an A level Cambridge question and seems too long winded for students compared to other languages.

Comment: When you do `Myarray = [[0]*3]*3`, you're actually multiplying the references.  List comprehension is a one-line way to do it.

Comment: How much shorter would this be in other languages?

Comment: I like `[x[:] for x in [[0]*3]*3]` for non-numpy 2D arrays but I'm in the minority on that one.

Comment: @ScottHunter: There are a few Python-like languages where it _is_ just `[[0]*3]*3`, because they don't do references right. Of course staying in Python, assuming you've done `from numpy import *`: `zeros((3,3))` is actually shorter, as well as better.

Answer (score 6):

With vanilla Python, you could use this, a nested list comprehension

```
>>> m = [[0 for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
>>> m
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Unlike the multiplied list you showed in your example, it has the desired behavior

```
>>> m[1][0] = 99
>>> m
[[0, 0, 0], [99, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

However, for serious use of multidimensional arrays and/or numerical programming, I'd suggest you use [**Numpy**](https://numpy.org/) arrays.

Comment: Better yet: [[0]*3 for x in range(3)]

Comment: Both the answer above and Scotts work just fine and I thank you both. For the purpose of A level Junuxx is more readable so gets the vote!