# Python: Implementation of shallow and deep copy constructors

Tags: python, copy-constructor, deep-copy

It is in most of the situations easy to implement copy constructors (or overloaded assignment operator) in C++ since there is a concept of pointers. However, I'm quite confused about how to implement shallow and deep copy in Python.

I know that there are special commands in one of the libraries but they don't work on classes that you have written by yourself. So what are the common ways to implement?

P.S. Showing process on some basic data structures (linked list or tree) will be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks, they worked, it was my mistake in syntax.
I am very interested in overwriting these functions with `__copy__()` and `__deep_copy()__`. For example. how can I make a deep copy without knowing which type of information is in a data structure?

Comment: What do you mean that libraries don't work on classes you have designed yourself? What is wrong with `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The python [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) can reuse the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) interface for letting classes customize copy behaviour.

The default for instances of custom classes is to create a new, empty class, swap out the `__class__` attribute, then for shallow copies, just update the `__dict__` on the copy with the values from the original. A deep copy recurses over the `__dict__` instead.

Otherwise, you specify a `__getstate__()` method to return internal state. This can be any structure that your class `__setstate__()` can accept again.

You can also specify the `__copy__()` and/or `__deepcopy__()` methods to control *just* copy behaviour. These methods are expected to do all the copying themselves, the `__deepcopy__()` method is passed a memo mapping to pass on to recursive `deepcopy()` calls.

An example could be:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.spam = expression + that * generates - ham   # calculated

    def __copy__(self):
        # self.spam is to be ignored, it is calculated anew for the copy
        # create a new copy of ourselves *reusing* self.bar
        return type(self)(self.bar)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        # self.spam is to be ignored, it is calculated anew for the copy
        # create a new copy of ourselves with a deep copy of self.bar
        # pass on the memo mapping to recursive calls to copy.deepcopy
        return type(self)(deepcopy(self.bar, memo))
```

This example defines custom copy hooks to prevent `self.spam` being copied too, as a new instance will calculate it anew.

Comment: i am very interested in the last solution. how can i copy one value from another without knowing the type? should i just write for all types or is there any simpler solution to that?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: you delegate contained values to a `copy.deepcopy` recursive call instead. It'll handle different types.