# deep copy with filtering in python

Tags: python, json, filter, deep-copy

I want to make a deep copy of a python data structure, ignoring some of the elements based on some criteria.

E.g., the input could be arbitrary json, and I'd like to copy everything *but* dictionaries with 'ignore' key in them. Like this:

```
def my_filter(entry):
    # return true if we need to skip this entry
    if not isinstance(entry, dict): return False
    return ('ignore' in entry)

a = [
    {"free": "yourself", "ignore": ""},
    [
        {"two": "words" },
        {"one": "finger"},
        [{"apples": 2}, {"array": [1,2,3,4], "ignore": ""}],
    ],
    {"hi": "there", "ignore": ""},
]

print copy_with_filter(a, my_filter)
```

and it would output

```
[[{'two': 'words'}, {'one': 'finger'}, [{'apples': 2}]]]
```

I've implemented this code which does the job for json input, that is when only list, dict, or literals can be present, and it works well:

```
def copy_with_filter(a, filter_func):
    # assume input is either list, or dict, or "literal" (i.e. string/int/float)
    if isinstance(a, list):
        out = [ copy_with_filter(x, filter_func) for x in a if not filter_func(x) ]
    elif isinstance(a, dict):
        out = a.copy() # shallow copy first
        for k in a.iterkeys():
            # replace values with filtered deep copies
            out[k] = copy_with_filter(a[k], filter_func)
    else:
        out = a
    return out
```

Though my question is whether there's more generic/better/built-in way of doing a deep copy with filtering in python?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Python deepcopy builtin with memoization - that works better when deep copying a structure which has cross-referenced resources - your approach will create duplicates of things which are referenced multiple times in the children of the root object.

The somewhat terrible Python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

... but there are good tutorials out there. One SO post on overloading the copy constructors for custom classes:

[Python: Implementation of shallow and deep copy constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684881/python-implementation-of-shallow-and-deep-copy-constructors)

Adding filtering is a little more fiddly - but for custom objects it's easy enough (just early out of the **deepcopy** constructor, without adding a new object to the memo dict - the only real difficulty is plumbing in custom filtering rules, but that's just plumbing).