# Python - point class not getting correct output

Tags: python

So I have a point class and a line class that both have a scale method.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")
        self.x = x
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
        self.y = y

    def scale(self, f):
        if not isinstance(f, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"f\" illegal.")
        self.x = f * self.x
        self.y = f * self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d %d' % (int(round(self.x)), int(round(self.y)))

class Line:

    def __init__(self, point0, point1):
        self.point0 = point0
        self.point1 = point1

    def scale(self, factor):
        if not isinstance(factor, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"factor\" illegal.")
        self.point0.scale(factor)
        self.point1.scale(factor)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.point0, self.point1)
```

So one of the tests I do on this code is to check for a shallow copy which I do in this test code.

```
p0.scale(2.0)
p1.scale(2.0)
print line
```

The problem is the print line gives me 0 2 4 6 and it should give me 0 1 2 3. So why is it printing multiples of 2 instead? The scale method is supposed to return the scaled values and for all the other test cases it prints the expected values however just with this test code it prints values I didn't expect. Here's how the values of p0 and p1 are set up:

```
print '********** Line'
print '*** constructor'
p0 = Point(0.0, 1.0)
p1 = Point(2.0, 3.0)
line = Line(p0,p1)
print line
```

Comment: what is p0 and p1 before scale?

Comment: Please show the construction of `p0`, `p1`, and  `line`.

Comment: Ok I updated the code to show the construction of p0, p1 and line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__` method for `Line`, you are assigning the names `self.point0` and `self.point1` to the two points that are passed in. This does not make a new copy, only gives the objects in memory another name. If you change this method to

```
def __init__(self, point0, point1):
    self.point0 = Point(point0.x, point0.y)
    self.point1 = Point(point1.x, point1.y)
```

then everything should work as intended. Or, you can use the copy module:

```
from copy import copy

class Line:
    def __init__(self, point0, point1):
        self.point0 = copy(point0)
        self.point1 = copy(point1)
```

You could also define your own `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods on your `Point` class.

```
def __copy__(self):
    return type(self)(self.x, self.y)

def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    return type(self)(self.x, self.y)
```

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684881/python-implementation-of-shallow-and-deep-copy-constructors) for more information.

Comment: What is the advantage of defining your own `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods? In other words, why _should_ one do this?

Comment: @martineau I changed "should" to "could" because I don't really have an answer to that. With `__copy__` you get a lot more control over what happens (rather than `__dict__` being copied the old instance to the new instance), but it seems like this would only be situationally beneficial. Do you have an actual answer to your question?

Comment: Only situation I can think of would be if, say, what `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()` would do was wrong or inappropriate for some reason. For example if the latter would copy too much.

Answer (score 0):

Printing `line` after scaling `p0,p1` by 2 multiply `x,y` pairs for `p0, p1`. Line instance values of `point0` and `point1` pointing to instances of `Point` which is p0 and p1 appropriately,  as result of `print line`  you can see updated value of `x,y` of each point.

```
p0 = Point(0,1)
p1 = Point(2,3)
line = Line(p0, p1)
print line # 0 1 2 3
p0.scale(2.0)
p1.scale(2.0)
print line # 0 2 4 6
```