# Python deepcopy not copying right

Tags: python, inheritance, deep-copy

I have a class `NodesGIS(GeoDataFrame)` (NodesGIS therefore inherits from GeoDataFrame). I also have a class `WaterNetworkModel` whose attributes include an instance of `NodesGIS` called `nodes_gis`.

However, when I deepcopy an instance of `WaterNetWorkModel`, the attribute `nodes_gis` in the copy is a `GeoDataFrame`. To make it more clear:

```py
>>> type(wn.nodes_gis) # wn is an instance of WaterNetWorkModel
<class 'wntr.network.model.NodesGIS'>
>>> type(deepcopy(wn).nodes_gis)
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
```

How can I make the attribute `nodes_gis` in the deep copy also have the type NodesGIS?

Comment: Your subclass needs an `__deepcophy__` method that returns an instance of its own class. Otherwise it inherits the one from `GeoDataFrame`, which doesn't know how to create an instance of the subclass.

Comment: This post on [Python: Implementation of shallow and deep copy constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684881/python-implementation-of-shallow-and-deep-copy-constructors) may be helpful for implementing your own `__deepcopy__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions by @Barmar and @E. Turok in the comments of my question, I solved my problem by implementing `__deepcopy__` in my child class `NodesGIS` as follows:

```py
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo=...):
        self.__deepcopy__ = None # This is important to avoid recursion, given deepcopy() is the same as self.__deepcopy__()
        return NodesGIS(deepcopy(self, memo))
```

Comment: `self.__deepcopy__ = None # This is important to avoid recursion, given deepcopy() is the same as self.__deepcopy__()` ???

Comment: You are supposed to updat ethe memo dict probably