# strang behavior of 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, append

I creat a 2d array using two methods they look the same

```
helper1=[[]]*5
helper=[[] for i in range(5)]
```

when I append new element to the arrays, they behave differently

```
helper1[0].append(1) 
result is [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
helper[0].append(1)
result is [[1], [], [], [], []]
```

I am surprised by the first outcome , why it is so? thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element (array) "multiplication" vs. list comprehension initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933257/element-array-multiplication-vs-list-comprehension-initialization)

Comment: @jonSG thank you! I guess something like this, was surprised