# for n in a list: del n

Tags: python, loops, scope

When I loop over a list, the name that I give within the loop to the elements of the list apparently refers directly to each element in turn, as evidenced by:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for n in a:
...     print n is a[a.index(n)]
True
True
True
```

So why doesn't this seem to do anything?

```
>>> for n in a: del n
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

If I try `del a[a.index(n)]`, I get wonky behavior, but at least it's behavior I can understand - every time I delete an element, I shorten the list, changing the indices of the other elements, so I end up deleting every other element of the list:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for n in a: del a[a.index(n)]
>>> a
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Clearly I'm allowed to delete from the list while iterating. So what's going on when I try to `del n` inside the loop? Is anything being deleted?

Comment: Related:[Updating elements in nested list using 'for' won't work in python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650945/updating-elements-in-nested-list-using-for-wont-work-in-python-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the block of any `for n in X` statement, `n` refers to the variable named `n` itself, not to any notion of "the place in the list of the last value you iterated over". Therefore, what your loop is doing is repeatedly binding a variable `n` to a value fetched from the list and then immediately unbinding that same variable again. The `del n` statement only affects your local variable bindings, rather than the list.

Comment: Agreed, you're deleting n, not an element of the list.

Comment: Deleting an element from a list is going to slide things to the left to fill the gap.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing this:

```
some_reference = a[0]
del some_reference
#do you expect this to delete a[0]? it doesn't.
```

You're operating on a variable bound to the value of `a[0]` (then one bound to `a[1]`, then...).  You can delete it, but it won't do anything to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained the idea of deleting a reference pretty well, I just wanted to touch on item deletion for completeness. Even though you use similar syntax, `del a[1]`, each type will handle item deletion a little differently. As expected, deleting items from most containers just removes them, and some types do not support item deleting at all, tuples for example. Just as a fun exerciser:

```
class A(object):
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        print 'I will NOT delete item {}!'.format(index)

a = A()
del a[3]
# I will NOT delete item 3!
```

Answer (score 1):

Dolda2000's answer covers the main question very nicely, but there are three other issues here.

---

Using `index(n)` within a `for n in a` loop is almost always a bad idea.

It's incorrect:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2]
for n in a:
    print(a.index(n))
```

This will print `0`, then `1`, then `0` again. Why? Well, the third value is `1`. `a.index(1)` is the index of the first `1` in the list. And that's `0`, not `2`.

It's also slow: To find the `i`th value, you have to check the first `i` elements in the list. This turns a simple linear (fast) algorithm into a quadratic (slow) one.

Fortunately, Python has a nice tool to do exactly what you want, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    print(i)
```

Or, if you don't need the values at all, just the indices:

```
for i in len(range(a)):
    print(i)
```

(This appears as a hint in the docs at least twice, conveniently buried in places no novice would ever look. But it's also spelled out [early in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).)

---

Next, it looks like you were attempting to test for exactly the case Dolda2000 explained was happening, with this:

```
n is a[a.index(n)]
```

Why didn't that work? You proved that they are the same object, so why didn't deleting it do anything?

Unlike C-family languages, where variables are addresses where values (including references to other addresses) get stored, Python variables are names that you bind to values that exist on their own somewhere else. So variables can't reference other variables, but they can be names for the same value. The `is` expression tests whether two expressions name the same value. So, you proved that you had two names for the same value, you deleted one of those names, but the other name, and the value, are still there.

An example is worth 1000 words, so run this:

```
a = object() # this guarantees us a completely unique value
b = a
print a, b, id(a), id(b), a is b
del b
print a, id(a)
```

(Of course if you also `del a`, then at some point Python *will* delete the value, but you can't see that, because by definition you no longer have any names to look at it with.)

---

> Clearly I'm allowed to delete from the list while iterating.

Well, sort of. Python leaves it undefined what happens when you mutate an iterable while iterating over it—but it does have special language that describes what happens for builtin mutable sequences (which means `list`) in the [`for`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) docs), and for `dict`s (I can't remember where, but it says somewhere that it can't guarantee to raise a `RuntimeError`, which implies that it *should* raise a `RuntimeError`).

So, if you *know* that `a` is a `list`, rather than some subclass of `list` or third-party sequence class, you *are* allowed to delete from it while iterating, and to expect the "skipping" behavior if the elements you're deleting are at or to the left of the iterator. But it's pretty hard to think of a realistic good use for that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you do

```
for n in a: del a[a.index(n)]
```

Try this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for n in a: print(n, a); del a[a.index(n)]
```

This is what you get:

```
(0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
(2, [1, 2, 3, 4])
(4, [1, 3, 4])
```

Thus n is just a tracker of the index, and you can think this way. Every time the function iterates, n moves on to the next relative position in the iterable. 
In this case, n refers to a[0] for the first time, a[1] for the second time, a[2] for the third time. After that there is no nextItem in the list, thus the iterations stops.