# Shortest way to input each and every element of a 2D Matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, matrix, input

I would like to know a short method to input the elements of a 2D matrix one by one. (Using only default python modules)

My current code:

```
i= []
for x in range(3):
    i.append(map(int, raw_input("enter the element").split()))
    for y in range(3):
        i.append(map(int, raw_input("enter the element").split()))
print i
```

I want the result to be like :

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

But end up getting:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]
```

I have already checked for potential duplicates, but could not find any that would take each and every element of the matrix.

Any short method would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The rows and columns should be changeable separately.
So, if we enter 3 rows and 4 columns, the elements should be automatically placed into their respective locations.

Example: For a 2x2 matrix

If the input is: `1,2,1,2`

Then the matrix should be :

```
[[1,2],
 [1,2]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or this:

**UPDATE:**
changed to the format i guessed you'd want :)

```
rows = 3
cols = 3
result = [[int(raw_input("row: %d col: %d  => " % (row, col))) 
           for col in xrange(cols)] for row in xrange(rows)]
```

Comment: The program still outputs [[1], [2], [3]] instead of my desired result. I think it would be better if you had another variable for columns.

Comment: what do u insert in raw_input?

Comment: what is your desired format for inserting in raw_input?

Comment: Just entering each number and hitting enter is enough. It works, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Verbose, but works:

```
M = []
for i in range(rows):
    row = []
    M.append(row)
    for j in range(rows):
        x = raw_input("Number for element ({}, {}): ".format(i, j))
        row.append(int(x))
```

If you are working on matrices, you should also give NumPy a look.
Then you could have done it as:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array((rows, cols))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
         M[i, j] = int(raw_input("Number: "))
```

Comment: I always use numpy, but in school, we aren't allowed to use modules other than default :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
i= []
for x in range(3):
    i.append([int(j) for j in raw_input("enter the element").split()])

print i
```

Comment: Please check edit. Your program has equal columns and rows, moreover your result comes to be : [[1], [2], [3]]