# How to read user defined input for 2d array

Tags: python, list, input

I have to read an n*n matrix where n and as well the elements of the matrix should be obtained from the user in the console. I understand that Python sees a 2d array to be list in a list. I have read values for a matrix in C and C++. But it seems different in Python. I went through some examples and in all examples I was able to see only compile time input. How do we give user defined output from user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already stated, you will have to use a list of lists.

```
main_list = []
for i in range(n):
  temp_list = []
  for j in range(n):
    temp_list.append(raw_input("Element {0}:{1}: ".format(i,j)))
  main_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to traverse through the elements. Like how to locate main_list[i][j], i.e row1 element2 or something like that.

Comment: exactly the way you stated. After running this, print `main_list` in the end. Now this would look similar to C/C++ 2d array. Use python syntax and C/C++ logic that you know to traverse this array/list.

Comment: Thank you. But list within lists is lot more confusing as we increase the dimensions.

Comment: True but when you are comparing it with a C/C++ array, only the name has changed, you have the same thing everywhere. So your access to an element is like main_list[1][2] at all the places.

Comment: Am getting familiar now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a list for each row and append them to the main list.

```
matrix=[]    
for i in xrange(n):
    lst=raw_input().split()
    matrix.append(lst)
```

Comment: But how can you be sure that the number of columns will be same. What if the array is to be of size 3*2