# How to create a 2d list from a input data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I was trying this

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
print(n,m)
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        ar[i][j] = int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        print (ar[i][j])
```

But it was showing an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shivansh/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    ar[i][j] = int(input())
NameError: name 'ar' is not defined
```

I used to do the same in C language but it works. So, how to this in Python?

Comment: Create an empty list ar outside of loop at your declarations.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python-3-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't declared `ar` yet. In Python, you don't have to perform separate declaration and initialization; nevertheless, you can't perform *operations* on names willy-nilly.

Start off with something like this:

```
ar = [[0 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should know that `ar` is not defined when you are trying to perform an assignment like `ar[i][j] = int(input())`, there are many ways to fix that.

### In C/C++

In C/C++, I presume you would do such work like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    int **ar = new int*[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ar[i] = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &ar[i][j]);
    // Do what you want to do
    
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        delete ar[i];
    delete ar;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Before you get inputs by `scanf` in C/C++, you should allocate storage by calling `new` or `malloc`, then you can perform your `scanf`, or it will crash.

### How to do like that in Python

It's very similar to what you had done in C/C++, according to your code, when you are trying to perform assignment to `ar[i][j]`, Python has no idea what `ar` it is! So you have to let it know first.

### A NOT-pythonic way

A NOT-Pythonic way is do something like you did in C/C++:

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())

ar = []
for i in range(m):
    ar.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        k = int(input())
        ar[i].append(k)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print(ar[i][j])
```

You initialize the list by `ar = []` like you did `int **ar = new int*[m];` in C/C++. For each row in the 2-d list, initialize the row by using `ar.append([])` like you did `ar[i] = new int[n];` in C/C++. Then, get your data by using `input` and append it to `ar[i]`.

### A pythonic way

The way to perform such a job like above it's not very pythonic, instead, you can get it done by using a feature called [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then the code can be simplified into this:

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())

ar = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        k = int(input())
        ar[i][j] = k

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print(ar[i][j])
```

Note that the core `ar = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]` is a list comprehension that it creates a list which has `m` lists and for each list of these `m` lists it has `n` 0s.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize matrix in nested loop like this:

```
n = int(input()) # columns
m = int(input()) # rows
print(n,m)
matrix = []
for i in range(0,m):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(0,n):
        matrix[i].append(0)
        matrix[i][j] = int(input())
print matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't declared ar before, you cannot assign elements  at specific indexes. You can decalre a two dimensional list in this manner initialized to a certain `value`.

```
arr = [[value]*c for _ in range(r)]
```

where `r` and `c` are desired number of rows and columns respectively

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need the column count. Just enter the number of rows and give your input space separated.

```
rows = int(input('Enter rows\n'))
my_list = []
for i in range(rows):
    my_list.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

At Python-3 we can easily take row and column input side by side as well as the data like a matrix by this process.

```
  n, m = map(int, input("Enter row and column : ").split())    
  matrix = []      
  for i in range(0, n):
      matrix.append(list(map(int, input().strip().split()))[:m])
```

also i found it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
list=[]

n=int(input("enter no  of rows"))

m=int(input("enter no of columns"))

for i in range(0,m):
    list.append([])
for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(0,m):
       list[i].append(j)
       list[i][j]=0
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        print("entry in row:",i+1,"entry in column:",j+1)
        list[i][j]=int(input())
print(list)
```

Comment: just indent the statement list.append([]) in the loop i missed it during typing