# Creating a 2D array from a single list of input integers separated by space

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, input

I was solving some problems at `geeksforgeeks` and I came across a particluar question where the inputs are provided in the test case as shown:

```
2 2           # denotes row, column of the matrix
1 0 0 0       # all the elements of the matrix in a single line separated by a single space.
```

I am not getting how to initialize my 2D array with the inputs given in such a manner.

P.S. I can't use split as it will split all the elements on in a single array from which I have to read again each element. I am looking for more simple and pythonic way.

Comment: Related: [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.split`. And you also need to convert the split string items to `int`. But you can do that very compactly, if you want to:

```
rows, cols = map(int, input('rows cols: ').split())
data = map(int, input('data: ').split())
mat = [*map(list, zip(*[data] * cols))]
print(rows, cols)
print(mat)
```

**demo**

```
rows cols: 2 2
data: 1 2 3 4
2 2
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

---

If you get a SyntaxError on `mat = [*map(list, zip(*[data] * cols))]` change it to

```
mat = list(map(list, zip(*[data] * cols)))
```

Or upgrade to a newer Python 3. ;)

Answer (score 0):

After using split on both strings:

```
n_rows, n_cols = [int(x) for x in matrix_info_str.split(' ')]
split_str = matrix_str.split(' ')
```

I'd got with:

```
matrix = [split_str[i : i + n_cols] for i in xrange(0, n_rows * n_cols, n_cols)]
```