# How to create 2D matrix with single line input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, matrix

I've been trying to create a matrix, with single line input, like, if I enter "1 2 3" it should go like l[0][0]=[1,2,3]

```
for i in range(num):
  for j in range(num):
    l[i][j] = input().spilt()
```

It gives index out of range error, which I understand why it gives,
 since we are fixing j index at point of loop, which means we locking it to one entry and giving multiple input, which is contradicting, for removing the limiter, I modified it like this:

```
for i in range(num):
  l[i] = input().spilt()
```

I know this totally wrong, It is no where near to 2D matrix, but I'm totally screwed thinking over this.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `index out of range` is raised by the `l[i][j]` expression for some value of `i` or `j`.  Evidently `l` is a list or list of lists, and isn't as big as the `num` range.  WIthout knowing how you created `l` we really can't help you.  You can certainly put a list `['1','2','3']` in another list.

Comment: At some level you are confusing Python lists with numpy arrays (and possibly `np.matrix` array subclass).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you would want to do the following:

```
l = []
for _ in range(num):
    l.append(input().split())
```

Please note that `split()` is returning strings (that were parts of the input) and not integer numbers. If you want to have a list of lists of *numbers* (i.e., `float` or `int`), then you will want to convert strings to numbers of appropriate type:

```
l = []
for _ in range(num):
    l.append(list(map(float, input().split()))) # float <-> int (if needed)
```

or, if you insist on one-liners:

```
l = [list(map(float, input().split())) for _ in range(num)]
```

Also note that Python does not have the notion of 2D *arrays*. That is a concept in the `numpy` package. You also tagged your question with `numpy`. So, if your purpose is to input a square 2D `numpy` array you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([input('Enter line: ').split() for _ in range(num)], dtype=np.float)
```

Example:

```
In [18]: np.array([input('Enter line: ').split() for _ in range(num)], dtype=np.float)
Enter line: 1 2 3
Enter line: 4 5 6
Enter line: 7 8 9
Out[18]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
```