# How to create a 2D list from user input with separate prompts for each column

Tags: arrays, list, input, append

I'm trying to append to a list in Python 3 but want to do this in the shortest amount of lines possible. In order to do this, I have created a blank 1D array and used basic iteration to append to it. I want to append the 2d array within the iteration as well as allowing the user to be able to input their data to the 2d arrays. I know the code below doesn't work. However, I wanted to know if this is possible to achieve?

I'd like the output to be like the following:

```
[First name, Second name], [First name, Second name], [First name, Second name]
```

```
Array = []

for i in range (0,4):
    Array.append([input("First name")][input("Second name")])

print(Array)
```

Comment: More general question for reference: [How to input matrix (2D list) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741030/how-to-input-matrix-2d-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. I understand that you want the output as:

```
[['Aaron', 'Armstrong'],['Barry', 'Batista'], ['Cindy', 'Wilson']]
```

And that you want least number of lines as possible, so this is how short I was able to make it using List Comprehension:

```
Array = [[input("First Name: "), input("Last Name: ")] for _ in range(4)]
print(Array)
```

Or make it one line with :

```
print([[input("First Name: "), input("Last Name: ")] for _ in range(4)])
```

Comment: @Python3D If you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong, it's unclear what you want to do.
I'm assuming you want a list like :

`[
  ["Mark", "Wahlberg"],
  ["Matt", "Damon"]
]`

you can do that like :

```py
num_names = 5
name_arr = []

for i in range(num_names):
   temp_arr = list(input("Enter name space separated: ").split(" "))
   name_arr.append(temp_arr)
```

Enter your name like : "Matt Damon", it splits it into 2 strings and creates a list.