# How do I preallocate a matrix of any size and fill it in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am newer to Python (used to work in IDL and MATLAB) and am trying to get used to how Python "indexes" arrays. I am trying to initiate a 7x13 matrix and fill it in a for loop:

```
def func(theta2, phi2):
    sph = [[[] for l in range(6)] for m in range(12)] 
    for l in range(0,6):
        for m in range(-6,6):
            sph[l,m]=np.real(np.conjugate(sph_harm(m,l,phi2,theta2))*np.sin(theta2))
    return sph

f = func(np.pi/4,np.pi/4)
```

This results in this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple 
". If I remove the [l,m] index on my variable "sph", I only get a 1x1 array output instead of the desired 7x13 array output.

I have also tried removing the for loops all together and combining it all into one line:

```
def func(theta2, phi2):
    sph = [[np.real(np.conjugate(sph_harm(m,l,phi2,theta2))*np.sin(theta2)) for l in range(6)] for m in range(-6,6)]
    return sph
f = func(np.pi/4,np.pi/4)
```

This resulted in a list of 12, 1x6 arrays which is also not what I wanted.

This is similar to this post: [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly implement what was suggested in the responses here.

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NumPy you should not write loops.

Define your `m` and `l,` here called `x` and `y,`as arrays:

```
zeros = np.zeros((7, 13))
x = zeros + np.arange(7).reshape(7, 1)
y = zeros + np.arange(-6, 7)
```

Write your function `sph_harm()` so that it works with whole arrays. For example:

```
def sph_harm(x, y, phi2, theta2):
    return x + y * phi2 * theta2
```

Now, creating your array is much simpler, again working with whole arrays:

```
def func(theta2, phi2):
    zeros = np.zeros((7, 13))
    x = zeros + np.arange(7).reshape(7, 1)
    y = zeros + np.arange(-6, 7)
    return np.real(np.conjugate(sph_harm(x, y, phi2, theta2)) * np.sin(theta2))

f = func(np.pi/4, np.pi/4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because question title doesn't mention NumPy (but question body and all answers does) I just put below the code in **"pure" Python** for anybody who get here from Google and doesn't need NumPy solutions.

```
m = [[0] * col_count for _ in range(row_count)]
```

Result:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
sph[l,m]=np.real(np.conjugate(sph_harm(m,l,phi2,theta2))*np.sin(theta2))
```

into

```
sph[l][m]=np.real(np.conjugate(sph_harm(m,l,phi2,theta2))*np.sin(theta2))
```

and

```
>>> list(range(6))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(range(0,6))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

range(n) gives you a list from 0 to n-1

Comment: what do you mean? Stellar wants 7 object writing range(6), that's wrong, and you cannot pure python list contained in another pure python list by [a,b]