# python operator "*" with List， any others like it?

Tags: python, list

When using * to create list like:

```
>>> ll = [None] * 3
>>> ll
[None, None, None]
>>> ll[0] = 2
>>> ll
[2, None, None]
```

And then using two dimension,

```
>>> ll2 = 3 *[ 3 * [None]]
>>> ll2
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> ll2[0][0] = 2
>>> ll2
[[2, None, None], [2, None, None], [2, None, None]]
```

So, create list by operator *, if the element is object like list. It doesn't create new object, just use the referenced object.

Are there any other operators like this in Python?

### Edit:

Sorry, My representation is bad.  What I want to know is, are there any other operators using like "*" will not create multiple reference.

Comment: *Are there any other operators like this* - like what?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't Google. Google is Google.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​To all the answerers - I think OP's asking about: *Are there any other operators like this in Python?* **Not:** *What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?*

Comment: @KevinGuan Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rogalski  That problem is what I know. And What I ask is, are there any other operators using like "*" will not create multiple reference.

Comment: [How to define two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python), [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus That is nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you multiply the list of lists, it will create multiple reference of the inner lists.

```
>>> lst = 3 * [3 * [None]]
>>> lst[0] is lst[1]
True
>>> lst[0] is lst[2]
True
```

You need to create separated lists. For example, using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [3 * [None] for i in range(3)]
>>> lst[0][0] = 2
>>> lst
[[2, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Comment: I know that, what I want to know is that, are there any other operators using like "*" will not create multiple reference.

Comment: @YanhuiZhou, No operator that does what you want exists as far as I know.

Comment: OK, thanks. When I found this one, I desire to know to is there any others. And I can not search anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the `*` operator, but with the fact that you are using a `list`. `[3 * [None]]` creates a single list object, and you store a list of 3 references to this list in ll2. If you change one of the referenced lists, you change all the others, too. This behaviour will happen with all [mutable objects](http://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the use of the * operator for multiplying a list. The assignment is by reference or in other words l is a mutable alias. To demonstrate the point, the following code will do the same thing.

```
l = [None, None, None]
l12 = [l, l, l]
print l12
>>> [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
l[0]=2
print l12
>>> [[2, None, None], [2, None, None], [2, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension

```
>>> ll=[[None for r in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
>>> ll[0][0]=3
>>> ll
[[3, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```