# How to change values in a matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am trying to create a 12x12 matrix in Python. I set all locations to `"High"` then I try to set one particular location to `"Low"`.  In the print commands both are `"Low"` when I wanted the first one to be `"Low"` and I hoped the second was still `"High"` because it wasn't changed (I thought). What am I doing wrong?

```
HourlyUsageBlock = ["High" for x in range(12)]
WorkDayUsageBlock = [HourlyUsageBlock for x in range(12)]
Hour = 2
MinBlock = 6
WorkDayUsageBlock [MinBlock][Hour] = "Low"
print (WorkDayUsageBlock[6][2])
print (WorkDayUsageBlock[10][2])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: What you're doing wrong is you're putting a reference to the same thing (`HourlyUsageBlock`) in `WorkDayUsageBlock`. Your comprehension doesn't make a _copy_ , it just points to it. `WorkDayUsageBlock` is a list of things that point to the same exact `HourlyUsageBlock`.

Comment: @pvg: No, not a duplicate of that question IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the first two lines with:
    WorkDayUsageBlock = [["High" for x in range(12)] for y in range(12)]
and it works

Comment: Off-topic: If you're going to be writing much Python code, I suggest you read and follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It will make your code more readable to others (and yourself, eventually).

Comment: @martineau the problem gets mentioned but maybe not. It's definitely a dupe though, although it's one of those superdupes where it's hard to find the most canonical answer.

Comment: @pvg: Never heard of a "superdup" before. The accepted and highly up-voted answer to the linked question basically just describes [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which the OP obviously knows something about since their code uses them. However the answer's pretty vague about how exactly to apply them to a two-dimensional list, much less about how to avoid the problem mentioned in this question.

Comment: @martineau you haven't heard it because I made it up! The fundamental issue - not quite getting a handle on reference vs value is very, very common, you see python questions like that daily. There's got to be a canonical SO answer for that just like, say, the java tag has a 'Why am I getting an NPE and how do I fix it' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize `WorkDayUsageBlock` You basically put the same `HourlyUsageBlock` in every position. Because all elements in the WorkDay are the same list, changing one will change all.

Try this solution:

```
WorkDayUsageBlock = [["high" for x in range(12)] for y in range(12)]
```

Or, you can use lst.copy():

```
WorkDayUsageBlock = [HourlyUsageBlock.copy() for x in range(12)]
```

I suggest you to read about mutable and imutable objects in Python.

Comment: In Python 2, `list` objects like `HourlyUsageBlock` don't have a `copy()` method and it wasn't added until Python 3.3. However in both Python 2 & 3, one could obtain a copy of the `list` instance by using `[HourlyUsageBlock[:] for _ in range(12)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print (WorkDayUsageBlock)
[['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High'], ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High']]
```

> you could see every 3rd element of every row is 'Low' because comprehension just make use of same `HourlyUsageBlock`. So when you change the value of 3rd element, it gets reflected in every row as comprehension doesn't make copy of `HourlyUsageBlock`.