# Difference between 2 Ways of List Comprehensions in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I was using dynamic programming to implement the Matrix_Chain Problem, i.e. figure out the minimum number of multiplications to be done in matrix multiplication via parenthesizing. My code was not working until I changed the way of initializing list `m`. Could someone explain why, even when `m = [[0]*n]*n` and `m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]` make seemingly identical list, `m = [[0]*n]*n` will results in matrix entry not being correctly updated to the minimum cost?

I made list `m = [[0]*5]*5` and printed

```
for a in m:
  print(a)
```

I made list n = `[[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]` and also printed in the same way. The results are identical.

```
import sys
def Matrix_Chain (p, n):

  m = [[0]*n]*n #problematic step

  for i in range (1,n):
    m[i][i] =0

  for L in range(2, n):
     for i in range(1,n-L+1):    
        j = i + L -1
        m[i][j] = sys.maxsize

        for k in range (i, j):
        q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]
        if q <  m[i][j]:
          m[i][j] = q
   return m[1][n-1]
```

For argument `p = [1,2,3,4]` and `n = 4`, I expect to see `18`, the minimum number of multiplications. However, the `m = [[0]*n]*n` way will return `9223372036854775807`, which is the `sys.maxsize`.  The `m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]` way returns the correct answer `18`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There seems to be a lot of non-essential information here. Can you boil your question down to a [mcve]? See [ask]. Also, please take a look at our [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). There's lots of stuff in your question that might benefit from backticks (`\``).

Comment: Possible dup of [How to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

This is because

```
 m = [[0]*n]*n
```

Makes references of the same object in m. So m[0] is m[1] is ... is m[n-1]. This can be better understood with an example. Suppose you have:

```
m = [[0] * 3] * 3

print(a)
m[0][0] = 2
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
```

As you can see, changing an element in m[0] changes the same location in m[1] and m[2]. That is because m[1] and m[2] are simply references to m[0].

In the case of

```
m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
```

You actually create a new list for each location in m. Changing m[0] will not effect m[i] (for 0 < i < n).