# Python list comprehension performance

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I did some experiments with two ways to initialize a two-dimensional list.

I tested on both my local Macbook Pro and Leetcode playground, the result shows the first method is 4-5 times faster than the second method.

Can anyone explain the performance lagging of list comprehension?

```
n = 999
t0 = time.time()
arr1 = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
t1 = time.time()
print(t1 - t0)

t2 = time.time()
arr2 = [[None for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
t3 = time.time()
print(t3 - t2)
```

Comment: `[None]*n` is very fast, it allocates the underlying buffer exactly then does a C-level loop. `[None for _ in range(n)]` is a python level loop that uses append, which is amortized constant time but will involve buffer re-allocations

Comment: The first is a single loop.  The second is two loops, nested.  Did you try: `arr1 = [[[None] * n] * n]`?

Comment: And actually you want `[[None] * n for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: @RufusV2 you should use that, list repition doesn't copy objects so all the internal lists will be the same

Comment: Using a small value for n, print the arrays.  they are all different structures!   So it is a bad test for that reason too.

Comment: @RufusVS yes, but it actually doesn't make a huge difference, they are wrapping the inner lists in an additional list, which will take practically no time at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note, you are doing two different things. You meant to use:

```
[[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
```

You've wrapped your inner lists in an additional list, but that won't make a huge difference in the timing results. The list repetition version is definitely faster.

`[None]*n` is very fast, it allocates the underlying buffer exactly then does a C-level loop. `[None for _ in range(n)]` is a python level loop that uses append, which is amortized constant time but will involve buffer re-allocations.

Just looking at the bytecode gives a hint:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('[None]*n')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (n)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Basically, all the work is done in `BINARY_MULTIPLY`. For the list comprehension:

```
>>> dis.dis("[None for _ in range(n)]")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc06e31bea0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              8 LOAD_NAME                1 (n)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc06e31bea0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (_)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

The looping work is done at the Python interpreter level. Also, it grows the list through `.append`, which is algorithmically efficient, but will still be slower than what is done by list repetition, which is all pushed into the C layer.

Here is the C source code:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/48ed88a93bb0bbeaae9a4cfaa533e4edf13bcb51/Objects/listobject.c#L504

As you can see, it allocates the underlying buffer to the exact size it needs:

```
np = (PyListObject *) PyList_New(size);
```

Then, it does a quick loop, filling up the buffer without re-allocations. The most general case:

```
p = np->ob_item;
items = a->ob_item;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Py_SIZE(a); j++) {
        *p = items[j];
        Py_INCREF(*p);
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @juanpa, it has been a while since you posted this great answer. I'm wondering if there are ways to pre-allocate memory for the outer loop. I'm asking because as you certainly know, we can't use another `*` because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python/44382900#44382900

Comment: @F.S. no, and honestly, if you are looking for that sort of optimization, you should probably consider writing C extension / Cython, using `numpy` (perhaps with `numba`), or just using a different language

Comment: Okay that’s makes sense. I noticed this performance issue when i was working on a problem involving 2d array on Leetcode. Only the * method’s performance satisfies the online judge.

Comment: @F.S. usually, the point of the questions on places like Leetcode are to test your skills with *algorithms and data structures*. Probably, that was the issue, not some micro-optimization like this.

Comment: I agree. However I did meet a problem that micro-optimizing this one line makes the difference of passing or not so it's still good to know. Thanks for ur time!

Answer (score 1):

Just a toy experiment, and it can further speedup if creating arrays if element datatype is compatible with numpy

```py
%timeit [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
1.42 ms ± 6.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit [[None for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
17.3 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.zeros((n,n))
148 µs ± 440 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the different techniques were generating different structures (as I noted in a comment)  This rewrite yields the same structures, but as @juanpa arrivillaga pointed out, you are actually getting multiple references to a single list, which will show up when you start assigning values to array elements.

```
import time
from pprint import pprint

n = 999 # for time test

# n = 5 # for structure printout test.

t0 = time.time()
arr1 = [[None] * n] * n
t1 = time.time()
print(t1 - t0)

t0 = time.time()
arr2 = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
t1 = time.time()
print(t1 - t0)

t2 = time.time()
arr3 = [[None for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
t3 = time.time()
print(t3 - t2)

if n<20:
    print (len(arr1),len(arr1[0]))
    pprint (arr1)
    print (len(arr2),len(arr2[0]))
    pprint (arr2)
    print (len(arr3),len(arr3[0]))
    pprint (arr3)
```