# Possible non optimization in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I do the following:

```
import sys

for i in range(30):
    print(sys.getsizeof([1 for _ in range(i)]))
```

I get outputs that are powers of 2, whereas if I do this:

```
for i in range(30):
    print(sys.getsizeof([1]*i))
```

I get smaller sizes that are linearly increasing.

I'm trying to understand: it seems that in the first example, python is re-creating and growing the array in the list-comprehension loop as it is iterating over range(i). In the second example python seems able to allocate the final array only once and at the correct dimension. Why is it not able to figure it out in the first example? In my precise case it's easy to see that `range(i)` will always generate a array of size i

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement that the source object in a list comprehension be something whose length can be determined in advance; even in cases where it can, the possible presence of an `if` clause makes that length merely an upper bound on the result length.

Comment: I know there is no requirement I'm jus wondering why this simple setup (which is very common) isn't more optimized. The interpreter knows there is no if clause and can also know easily in lots of cases that the size of the output is determined

Comment: It seems the issue is not the lack of optimization for comprehensions but how `[x] * i` is actually optimized. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65445439/15032126

Comment: Philosophically, it is rarely worth the trouble to optimize initialization sequences like this, because they tend to be run once, and not as part of an inner loop.  It's usually not the bottleneck.

Comment: In case of  list comprehension I see output that increases from 56 by 32 on each 4th step. Where did you get power of two?

Comment: @lezebulon, I don't understand your point. It's obvious that optimizing the first case is much more difficult than optimizing the second case, because the list comprehension compiler should inspect a sequence or an iterator(after the 'in') eagerly and find out its bound.

Comment: @relent95 the "compiler" doesn''t need to find out any bound, it just has to detect when the sequence is not an iterator, and in that case when the sequence is computed and in memory, the runtime can allocate the correct size for the for-comprehension

Comment: @lezebulon, introducing another dispatch for that specific case will hurt the overall performance and cause a maintenance problem(likely to form spaghetti code). Currently, the ```range()``` is dealt as an iterator. See [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Python/compile.c#L5638) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Objects/rangeobject.c#L791).