# Updating an 2d array created using 2 * operator produces unexpected side effect in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I tried making a 2d array using 2 approaches in python. Why does approach 1 provide an unexpected side effect where all the rows get updated?

```
dp1 = [ [0] * 5 ] * 8
dp1[2][2] = dp1[1][1] + 1

print("DP1")
for dp in dp1: print(dp)

dp2 = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(8)]
dp2[2][2] = dp2[1][1] + 1

print("DP2")
for dp in dp2: print(dp)
```

Output:

```
DP1
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]


DP2
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842423/7552340

Comment: So, that is not an array, that is a *list* which contains references to lists. In fact, what it contains is **8 references to the same list**, so  first `[0] * 5` list is created, let's call it `x`, then `[x]*8` creates another list, with 8 references *to the same list*

Comment: On the other hand `[[0] * 5 for _ in range(8)]` creates a new list, `[0]*5` 8 times.

Comment: @Damzaky that answer is just wrong. Python *never* uses call by reference